# d3 axis not scaling as per range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, responsive-design

I am trying to create a responsive graph in d3.
This is the code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="svg_container">
    </div>
</body>
<style>
    #container{
    width: 90%;
    height: 50vh;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
<script>



    var width = 800,
        height = 425,
        aspect = width / height;

    console.log(width,height,aspect);
    var margin= 20;
    var canvas = d3.select("#container")
                   .append("svg")
                   .attr("width", width)
                   .attr("height", height)
                   .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
                   .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMid")
                   .style("border","1px solid black");

    var g = canvas.append("g")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin+ "," + margin + ")");                   



    window.addEventListener("load", resize);
    window.addEventListener("resize", resize);


    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
              .domain([0,25]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(x);  

    var xg = g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .call(xAxis);         




    function resize(){
        d3.csv("time.csv", data =>{
        var targetWidth= document.getElementById("container").offsetWidth;

        var targetHeight = targetWidth/aspect;

        canvas.attr("width", targetWidth);
        canvas.attr("height", targetHeight);

        x.range([0, targetWidth]);
        xAxis.scale(x);

        console.log(targetWidth, x.range());

        xg.call(xAxis);

        });
    }

</script>
</html>
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/wek7r6Ld/2/) is the fiddle
However, while both the svg and the axis are responsive, the axis doesn't seem to be of the right dimension. (Console.log(x.range()) shows the range to be equal to the (responsive) width, but the generated axis doesn't appear to be so.

Comment: use a version control system

Comment: if you remove the `viewbox` attribute it looks a lot better, still the size is not perfect. draw a `rect` with `width` equal to `targetWidth` below your axis and you see the axis **is** using the correct width

Comment: `x.range([0, targetWidth-2*margin]);`